# AuthorizationRuleCollection - A way to find out if a specific rule exists?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find out if a directory has a specific access rule. But there is no "Contains". So I wrote an extension method which works fine.

Now in the next step I want to make the LINQ `.Exist(r => r.Identity == "identifier")` available, so I can check for an item with specific properties.

How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `.Any(r => r.Identity == "identifier")`

Or, if you insist on having an `Exist` method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Exist<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return items.Any(predicate);
    }
}
```